# Unable to execute my command after SSH in remote server

Tags: java, shell, process

I have written a code that does SSH in servers and runs a Java file with arguments.

The problem I am facing is that the code successfully does SSH in but it does not run the command after that. Strangely If I run the command from the server alone it works. Any suggestions on this please?
Following is the code:

```
public void  getSSH(String code, String newCode, JspWriter out){   

    try{
        File f = new File("/usr/site/html/Output.txt");
        BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
        String Servers[] = {"root@web233.xyz.com","root@web234.xyz.com","root@web235.xyz.com","root@web153.xyz.com"};
        for(int i =0;i<Servers.length && i<1 ;i++){

            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/site/swapimages.sh "+Servers[i]+" '/root/testRemote.sh "+ code+" "+ newCode+"'");
            out.println("/usr/site/swapimages.sh "+Servers[i]+" '/root/testRemote.sh "+ code+" "+ newCode+"'"+"<br>");
            Utils.waitFor(10000); 
        }

    }
}
```

I have also been recommended JSch but haven't looked into it yet.

Comment: does it run the command after the ssh session ends?

Comment: There is only one ...exec() there so I'd only expect it to run one command (...swapimages.sh). Were you expecting it to also run testRemote.sh in that same single ...exec() ?  Perhaps I'm missing something, but wont you need a second ...exec() for testRemote.sh?

Comment: Yeah I am running the testRemote.sh in the same exec command 
but it worked when i just ran it on the server ..

Comment: Could you show your `swapimages.sh` file?

Comment: If you need your local `swapimages` script, JSch can't really help you. It can only execute remote stuff.

Comment: paulo , the swapimages.sh is just for testing I was using. I basically have to run the java file after my successful ssh into the server.
String cmd = "nohup /usr/java/bin/java -cp /usr/site/html/WEB-INF/lib/eminent.jar com.eminent.revolve.SwapImages "+ code+" "+ newCode+" &";

Comment: So basically I am copying the jars first and run my SwapImages.java file. If I paste this command on the server it works but from my jsp file after I SSH this doesn't execute. I was using SwapImages.sh just in case to see if that worked !

Comment: I removed the `jsch` and ssh tags as this was in reality only a call-shell-from-java problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is that the quotes in this version don't have the same effect as they do on the command line.  When you call SSH from bash, you put the remote command in quotes so that it is all interpreted as a single argument.  Bash does the separation of the arguments for you.  With `exec`, Java is splitting up the arguments for you.  The [documentation for `exec`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.io.File%29) describes how it separates.  It uses a `StringTokenizer`, which is fairly dumb and seperates the line based on spaces (ignoring the quotes).  This means that the array of arguments passed into the command is something like:

```
{ "/usr/site/swapimages.sh", "root@something", "'/root/testRemote.sh",
  code, newCodeContents + "'" }
```

It could be even more strings if `code` or `newCode` have spaces in them.  Notice that your command is multiple elements in the array and will therefore be treated as multiple arguments by ssh.  In addition, `ssh` will actually try to execute a command that is in a directory that is named `'`.  What you want to pass in, though, is:

```
{ "/usr/site/swapimages.sh", "root@something",
  "/root/testRemote.sh " + codeContents + " " + newCodeContents }
```

Notice that there are no quotes and the whole command is the third element in the array.

So, you just need to manually create the string array and use the other form of `exec` that takes a string array and that should fix the problem.

Comment: You could also use `ProcessBuilder` to help with this too.

Comment: Thanks 101100 .. yeah that was the problem ! I wrote on single string of my command and it worked !! :)